# Prometheus: play controller is not showing counter result

Tags: scala, playframework, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and using play framework 2.4 I am using a counter metric here is my code

```
object CounterDemo {
  val requestTotal = Counter.build()
 .name("requests_total")
 .help("Total number of requests")
 .register();  
}

object MyController extends Controller {
   def counter() = Action {
   val responseWriter = new StringWriter();
   val result = TextFormat.write004(responseWriter, CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.metricFamilySamples()) 
   log.info("result is "+result)
   responseWriter.close()
   Ok("result"+result)  
   }

  def getAllDirectUser = Action {
    CounterDemo.requestTotal.inc()
    //other functionality 
  }
}
```

here is the route file

```
GET    /pom-metric                             controllers.MyController.counter

GET    /direct-user/list                                controllers.MyController.getAllDirectUser
```

I hit the route direct-user/list and /pom-metric route its returning nothing value 'result' is empty
i am a beginner in Prometheus please help where i am making a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types are there to help. Look at the type of `result`. It is `Unit` (AKA void)!

Obviously, the return type of the `TextFormat.write004` is `Unit` too, that's why the Scala compiler inferred the type of the `result` variable must be `Unit` as well.

This means `TextFormat.write004` is not a pure function, ie. it has side effects and does not return *any* value.  If you print a variable of type `Unit`, you get `()`.

Also, you construct a `StringWriter`, hand it over to TextFormat but you never look at its contents.

```scala
TextFormat.write004(
  responseWriter, CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.metricFamilySamples())

responseWriter.close()

val result = responseWriter.getBuffer.toString

Ok("result" + result)
```